# Как заменить стрелку (caret) select?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли изменить стрелку справа (caret), не заменяя весь фон? 
То есть, я хочу иметь возможность заменить иконку стрелки, но не трогать остальной вид select.

Видел решение, которое заменяет `background` целиком на новую картинку. Это решение рассматривать не будем.

Использовать модифицированный `button` тоже не хотелось бы.

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: просто заменить нельзя - стилизация не предусмотрена. надо слегка потанцевать с бубном, например, если в двух словах, можно создать слой поверх и ему через псевдоэлемент поставить нужную картинку на место стрелки. но тогда она не кликабельна будет.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

может так?

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.select:after {
  content: "▼";
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
select {
  padding-right: 25px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Сделать кроссбраузерно (так, чтобы выглядело везде одинаково), не получается, так как `select` не поддаются полной стилизации.

Comment: Это интересно. Спасибо. Но в FF выглядит как-то странно. Можно как-то кроссбраузерно?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1pcfz8ve/

Comment: В Safari большая разница. http://i.imgur.com/eJkEdrZ.png

Comment: это потому что select не поддаются полной стилизации

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ваш последний комментарий в ответ в чуть развёрнутом виде.

Answer (score 2):

Простой способ

```
.select { 
  width: 170px;  
  appearance: none; -убираем стандартную стрелку
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('../img/Rectangle.png') no-repeat right;  -вставляем нужную
}
```