# Можно ли сдвинуть стрелку (caret) в select с помощью стилей без замены?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, select

Есть список, у `select` края закруглены и теперь стрелка выбора (caret) смотрится некрасиво и прилипает к правому боку. Вопрос: можно ли сдвинуть ее левее на `20px` с помощью стилей и кроссбраузерно или без `js` никак?

Это не дубликат вопроса, т.к. меня полностью устраивает стандартная стрелка, я не хочу ее менять на картинку - вопрос в том: можно ли ее сдвинуть с помощью каких-либо хитростей или нет?

```css
select {
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заменить стрелку (caret) select?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483259/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-caret-select)

Comment: @Legionary нет, я спрашивал не как заменить стрелку, она меня устраивает, а сдвинуть. с помощью `pagging`, `margin`, псевдоэлементов или как-то по-другому

Comment: Это сделано с целью привлечь ваше внимание, что изменить положение стрелки нельзя, только визуальное отображение самой стрелки.

Comment: @Legionary понимаю. решил вопрос ниже

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете изменить стрелку на свою, а ее уже подвинуть как вам нужно

[Пример здесь](https://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/)

Comment: а, если мне не нужно ее менять на какую-то другую, меня эта устраивает  -я могу именно ее сдвинуть с помощью каких-либо хитростей или нет?

Comment: к сожалению такой возможности нет

Comment: хитрость есть, она банальная, странно, что никто никто здесь ее раньше не придумал - решил вопрос

Comment: @tCode, стоит перенести основное в ответ. Ответы ссылки не приветствуются.

Comment: @Grundy не вижу смысла дублировать информацию

Answer (score 1):

Придумал банальнейшее решение, которое спасает ситуацию

```css
body {
  background-color:gray;
}
div {
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
select {
  border: none;
  height: 44px;
  width: 180px;
}
select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```